# Timer job disable

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, development, timer-jobs

Can I raise some kind of event when a **timer job has been disabled** from central admin?
I need to logwhen a user disable a timer job. (without removing a feature)

Comment: Only SharePoint admins would be doing that and they would have a good reason to do so. This wouldn't be a situation that occurs often. That being said, I do not know of any events that fire on timer job deactivation.

Comment: Thanks, I know that only admin can do that, but I need to understand when they do that, I need to log farm account activities

Comment: There are no events for timer jobs or auditing to hook into

Comment: Sad, d you any idea about how can I log those actions? And log also if a user disable "my log sysem"?

Comment: If you created the timer job via feature, then in the feature deactivation code you could log something at least.

Comment: Thanks, I m doing that, but I still have the problem when tje timer job is disabled but the feature is enabled

Comment: another dirty approach is right a scirpt and run as schedule task every 5 min. which will check the status of the TImer jobs, if disable then send you alerts/email. from here if you want to check the who disabled it...then check the IIS logs and see who access that page from central admin.